# Why can I close my question as too broad or unclear?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Why is there an option for me to flag my question as *too broad* or *unclear what you're (I'm ?!) asking*?

I don't think anybody will use these flags for its own question! Flag as *duplicate* seems right, but other flags are not so useful for own posts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is multiple-personalities-friendly.

Comment: @MarounMaroun you mean SO is also friendly with people want to hurt themselves ? :)

Comment: GUI consistency? I agree it wont get used often, but it doesn't hurt anyone being there.

Comment: We vote on questions, not on people.  When you get a bunch of "what the heck is this about?" comments, can't delete the question anymore and don't want to do the work to fix the question then it is perfectly reasonable to help to get it closed quicker.

Comment: @HansPassant I think that's better be an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the same reason the Disciplined badge exists: for users who are self-aware and humble enough to acknowledge that their question isn't a good fit for the site or isn't clear after all, and for whatever reason choose not to edit their question — maybe they think a rewrite would take so long it's best to get it closed first to prevent answers, or they'd just rather get rid of it and forget about it than try to re-scope it or clarify it. (They could also just straight-up delete their question, but they won't be able to if there are already upvoted answers, which leaves closing as the next best recourse.)

Comment: Most people *can't* edit their bad questions into good questions, rather than just not being willing to.  In many cases it's either not possible, because the question is just that bad, or would be so difficult that it'd be beyond the ability of the author to know how to fix it.