# In which case should one flag its own post as "Should be closed" (not the "duplicate" flag case)?

Tags: support, flags, close-reasons

I post a question and notice I can flag it, but not like a regular post. The flagging window is shorter and has only three options:

[image]

If I choose the `Should be closed...` option I move to:

[image]

That seemed weird, so I looked up why and found *[Why can you flag your own question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346507/why-can-you-flag-your-own-question)* - which explains why the flag for `"**Moderator intervention**"` is needed.

I can also see the **reason for flagging my own post as duplicate** - if I found one, but I don't understand why I can flag my post as `Too broad`, `Un-clear what you asking`, `Primarily opinion base` and `off-topic`.

Obviously, if the question qualifies for one of those flag I can just delete or improve it - but I can not see why flagging it will help...

Should these flagging options be blocked for your own question? What is the purpose of them? Should we have only two options for self-flagging? (duplicate and moderator intervention)

**Edit** - I disagree with the duplication mark on this post. The other answer explains only when to mark your question as duplicate - which I state in my question is valid case. **This question is asking about the other reasons for flagging** (not "duplicate" or "moderator intervention").

Comment: If your question can be improved (without invalidating any existing answers), edit it. If it can’t be improved, and the system allows you to delete it (either less than two answers, or only one answer but it doesn’t have a positive score), delete it. If it can’t be improved and the system won’t let you delete it, then close it for the same reason you’d close any question. Doesn’t matter if it’s yours. If you want to know why any question should be closed (irrespective of whether it’s yours), there is a plethora of documentation on this site here.

Comment: But if it should be flag it also can be delete - if it has an answer with positive score (or more then one answer) then it probably should be close and not be flag (I assume people shouldn't answer question who are off-topic)

Comment: Those flags are the way you “vote to close” before you have the privilege to actually vote to close. They’re the same thing. And right, people shouldn’t be answering off topic questions: to prevent any (further) answers to off-topic questions is precisely the function of voting to close (or flagging, before you have the privilege) questions.

Comment: reason to close own question other than duplicate is laid out in [Why can I close my question as too broad or unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359625/839601)

Comment: @gnat - again I afraid I disagree - this link show my to close (or delete) the answer (which the OP can do) - I am talking about flags. I did some reasearch before posting this question. If you can explain **all** the reason for each case of the flagging to own answer I be glad if you can post it here as answer

Comment: I think you confusing between closing and flagging - all the answers on those link you sharing talking about my people close or delete their answer. I do agree with the reason said there. What I don't understand is my flagging them as such - the post owner can always delete them (and I already talk about case in which he cannot)...

Comment: @dWinder No, you are confusing closing and flagging. Flagging is the same as closing when you don’t have close privileges. It’s “closing light”. Everyone is telling you the same thing.

Comment: [Present simple tense, third person](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtfDp-2XEiA&t=2m29s)

Comment: I thinking I didn't explain myself good (@PeterMortensen - I will try to learn better - not an native English speaker).
I think some flagging are way to mark question for deletion (as vote for close if low on reputation). But, as if you can delete own post single-handed and no need to vote for close them you should not have the option to flag...
I still think it no duplicate of your links but I will give up the tries to explain myself

Answer (score 2):

Closing is for questions that cannot be answered (in the manner useful for SO's goals, anyway).

So if your question turns out to be such and you cannot delete it...

Comment: As I said in the comment - you can delete your question only if it has positive score answer which should be happening if your question is actually should be close (probably for grey area question it may happens but then the post owner wouldn't flag it as it is grey-area...)
And **if** this happens (which I believe it rare) - you can always flag for moderator...

Comment: @dWinder Unfortunately, people answer bad questions and upvote answers to bad questions all the time. That doesn't make them good questions. You should *not* use a custom moderator flag for that - their job is to handle things that regular users can't.